# ASP.NET Web API: verify if client has specific certifcate installed

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, certificate, asp.net-web-api2

We want to create a self signed certificate and manually install it on client PC's, with the private key marked as non-exportable.
The client calls a ASP.NET Web API, and there we want to check if that specific certificate is installed.

We want to do this as an additional method of authentication, to make sure that only valid clients can call the Web API. We know this is'nt waterproof because it is still possible to export the private key, but we have other additional authentication mechanisms such as a user password.

How can we achieve this? Or are there better ways to achieve our goal?

Comment: Is this host connected to the internet at all? or is this running on a network without any internet?

Comment: @Svek The client is a local installed Windows application, and the Web API runs on an internet server.

Comment: Assuming you have internet connectivity (not an isolated offline network) maybe take a look at alternative options just as `Let's Encrypt` -- it's free and might be easier to maintain overall versus trusting self-signed certs.

Answer (score 0):

For Me After I created the self signed certificate in the Server , I added he Certificate `Thumbprint` to my Client App

```
    private void setAppLocalSSL()
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate (
            object sender,
            X509Certificate cert,
            X509Chain chain,
            SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
            {
                return true;   //Is valid
            }

            // this is the Thumbprint of my local cert
            // your Cert Thumbprint instead of "0000000000000000"
            if (cert.GetCertHashString().ToLower() == "0000000000000000")
            {
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        };
    }
```

call `setAppLocalSSL` onload

Note : this is a WPF App.

Answer (score 0):

Three years later with .NET 7 there is an [official sample from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-7.0#handler-events) on how you can validate user certificates.

First, install the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Certificate](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Certificate) package. After that you can add the middleware in your `Program.cs`:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCertificate();
```

... and implement your own validations with `OnAuthenticationFailed` and `OnCertificateValidated`:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCertificate(options =>
    {
        options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnCertificateValidated = context =>
            {
                var claims = new[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, context.ClientCertificate.Subject, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.ClientCertificate.Subject, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer)
                };

                context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, context.Scheme.Name));
                context.Success();

                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });
```

If you don't know the certificate which the user is using, you can just call `context.Fail("Wrong certificate!")` inside the `OnCertificateValidated` method.